# SFTP storage event trigger stopped in live Azure synapse mode

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My Azure synapse account is linked with git and i am working on my feature branch and created storage event trigger that get files from SPTP server when i run pipeline manual. In master and feature branch it status is started but when i publish it into live mode its status become stop and while publishing i get this error message  Forbidden. Role based access check failed for resource /subscriptions
Some one know this issue

My main aim is to get the files from sftp server using storage event trigger

Comment: Are you able to publish other objects (pipelines, triggers)? If so, you may need a higher permission on the storage account where you want the storage event to occur.

Comment: @Chen Hirsh Yes i am able to publish all the pipeline, parameters ,linker service and data sets , all is good to go with pipeline just facing this issue because this blob is SFTP and we getting daily files in this blob and i want to use trigger on this blob that as we received new file the trigger will auto active and copy the files from SFTP to my blob container.

Comment: As I said, you probably don't have full permissions on the blob storage where you want to set the event trigger. Ask someone with full permission to try the publish.

Comment: If you have necessary permission and still you face the same issue, contact Azure support for troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/storage-event-trigger-permission-and-rbac-setting/ba-p/2101782), the user publishing the Storage Event Trigger is required to have :
*Microsoft.EventGrid/EventSubscriptions/Write* permission in the scope */subscriptions/####/resourceGroups/####/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageAccountName*.

This could be granted by adding a role assignment with Owner, Contributor or a custom role with only this specific permission.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your sharing knowledge, Yes it is role based access issue and person in my team which have all access create a trigger and attach it with pipeline and working fine

Comment: You are welcome @JunaidBilal . If that answer helped to solve your problem, can you accept it?